# How to convert latitude and longitude into (x,y) coordinates using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making my country's map using d3.js. I use the google maps url to  extract the longitude and latitude values of some points. In order to show a point using d3, I need to convert it into an (x,y) value in pixels and store it in an array of cities. I know this issue is about projection but I couldn't manage to solve it.

This is part of my code.

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], json);
var path = d3.geoPath().projection(projection); 


var URL =  "https://www.google.com.tr/maps/place/Ankara/@39.9035553,32.6223376,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14d347d520732db1:0xbdc57b0c0842b8d!8m2!3d39.9333635!4d32.8597419?hl=tr";

var splitUrl = URL.split('@');
var coords = splitUrl[1].split(',');

console.log(coords[0]); 
console.log(coords[1]); 

cities.push([coords[0], coords[1]]);
```

Comment: Converting a latitude and a longitude to an (x,y) value will always have some error because there is no way to fit a sphere onto a plane without deforming the sphere. Which method you should use to generate these (x,y) coordinates depends a lot on which purpose you are going to use these coordinates for. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like to plot the coordinates in my map retrieved from google maps link.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to convert your data to (x,y) pairs in pixels. When you use `d3.geoPath.projection(projection)` you've set your `d3.geoPath()` path generator to use the specified projection to automatically convert (latitude, longitude) pairs to (x,y) pairs.

What you need to do is take your (lat, long) pairs and use them to generate a GeoJSON object, which you can then feed to your `d3.geoPath` generator. You'll probably want a [GeoJSON point](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#pointhttp://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#point).

So your code should probably look like:

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], json);
var pathGenerator = d3.geoPath(projection);

var URL =  "https://www.google.com.tr/maps/place/Ankara/@39.9035553,32.6223376,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x14d347d520732db1:0xbdc57b0c0842b8d!8m2!3d39.9333635!4d32.8597419?hl=tr";

var splitUrl = URL.split('@');
var coords = splitUrl[1].split(',');

var geoJsonPoint = {
    type: "Point",
    coordinates: coords,
} 

pathGenerator.path(geoJsonPoint);
```

Comment: Why use  a path for a point? Would it not be more straight forward to simply use: `projection([long,lat])` which will return the projected x,y values for that point in a given projection?

Comment: That would be OK if they only wanted to get the projected coordinates, but they do in fact want to render the projected points, as they have stated in their question's comments.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Guess I focused to much on the "I need to convert it into an (x,y) value in pixels and store it in an array of cities."